# How to encode json from modified string json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I try to replace string by another string in json from database.
I can get the json, replace the content but I don't find a way to encode all the json after modification to replace in the database.

here is the json from database and function used:

```
{"cells":[{"data":"8h00","hidden":false,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-bold","wpdt-align-center","wpdt-bc-4A6081","wpdt-tc-FFFCFC","wpdt-ff-000007"]},{"data":"-70 Kg","hidden":false,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-bold","wpdt-ff-000007"]},{"data":"<a class=\"wpdt-link-content\" href=\"https:\/\/serre-chevalier-parapente.fr\/%%REPLACEME%%?vol=vp&date=Lundi%2020\/06\/2022&heure=8h00&map=0&poid=1\"  rel=\"\" target=\"_self\"><button class=\"button primary is-normal\" style=\"border-radius:99px;\">Vol p\u2019tit<\/button><\/a>","hidden":true,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-valign-middle"]},{"data":"","hidden":true,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-valign-middle"]},{"data":"<a class=\"wpdt-link-content\" href=\"https:\/\/serre-chevalier-parapente.fr\/reservation\/?vol=va&date=Lundi%2020\/06\/2022&heure=8h00&map=&poid=1\"  rel=\"\" target=\"_self\"><button class=\"button secondary is-normal\" style=\"border-radius:99px;\">Vol Aventure<\/button><\/a>","hidden":false,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-valign-middle"]},{"data":"<a class=\"wpdt-link-content\" href=\"https:\/\/serre-chevalier-parapente.fr\/reservation\/?vol=vp&date=Mardi%2021\/06\/2022&heure=8h00&map=0&poid=1\"  rel=\"\" target=\"_self\"><button class=\"button primary is-normal\" style=\"border-radius:99px;\">Vol p\u2019tit<\/button><\/a>","hidden":true,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-valign-middle"]},{"data":"","hidden":true,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-valign-middle"]},{"data":"<a class=\"wpdt-link-content\" href=\"https:\/\/serre-chevalier-parapente.fr\/reservation\/?vol=va&date=mardi%2021\/06\/2022&heure=8h00&map=&poid=1\"  rel=\"\" target=\"_self\"><button class=\"button secondary is-normal\" style=\"border-radius:99px;\">Vol Aventure<\/button><\/a>","hidden":false,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-valign-middle"]},{"data":"<a class=\"wpdt-link-content\" href=\"https:\/\/serre-chevalier-parapente.fr\/reservation\/?vol=vp&date=Mercredi%2022\/06\/2022&heure=8h00&map=0&poid=1\"  rel=\"\" target=\"_self\"><button class=\"button primary is-normal\" style=\"border-radius:99px;\">Vol p\u2019tit<\/button><\/a>","hidden":true,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-valign-middle"]},{"data":"","hidden":true,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-valign-middle"]},{"data":"<a class=\"wpdt-link-content\" href=\"https:\/\/serre-chevalier-parapente.fr\/reservation\/?vol=va&date=mercredi%2022\/06\/2022&heure=8h00&map=&poid=1\"  rel=\"\" target=\"_self\"><button class=\"button secondary is-normal\" style=\"border-radius:99px;\">Vol Aventure<\/button><\/a>","hidden":false,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-valign-middle"]},{"data":"<a class=\"wpdt-link-content\" href=\"https:\/\/serre-chevalier-parapente.fr\/reservation\/?vol=vp&date=Jeudi%2023\/06\/2022&heure=8h00&map=0&poid=1\"  rel=\"\" target=\"_self\"><button class=\"button primary is-normal\" style=\"border-radius:99px;\">Vol p\u2019tit<\/button><\/a>","hidden":true,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-valign-middle"]},{"data":"","hidden":true,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-valign-middle"]},{"data":"<a class=\"wpdt-link-content\" href=\"https:\/\/serre-chevalier-parapente.fr\/reservation\/?vol=va&date=Jeudi%2023\/06\/2022&heure=8h00&map=&poid=1\"  rel=\"\" target=\"_self\"><button class=\"button secondary is-normal\" style=\"border-radius:99px;\">Vol Aventure<\/button><\/a>","hidden":false,"type":"text","meta":["wpdt-fs-000013","wpdt-ff-000000"]}]}


$rep = "%%REPLACEME%%";

$field = 'locale';
$result = pll_current_language($field);
//function_alert($result);

switch ($result) {
    case "fr_FR":
        $string = "reservation/";
        break;
    case "en_GB":
        $string = "en/book/";
        break;
    case "es_ES":
        $string = "es/reservar/";
        break;
} $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wpdatatables_rows';
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT data, id FROM $table_name"
);

foreach($results as $row)
{
    $id = $row->id;
    //print_r($id);

    $data_json = $row->data;
    $decoded_json = json_decode($data_json, true);
    $datas = $decoded_json['cells'];
    //var_dump($datas);
    foreach($datas as $data) {
        $data = str_replace($rep,$string,$data['data']);
        var_dump($data);
    }

}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: JSON handling in PHP isn't uncommon, which functions did you find for that?

Comment: Agree, I can use json_encode() but question is more about how to encode all the data not only the modified part ? Actualy only $data['data'] was encoded.

Comment: Decode the whole JSON string, change the data. Then, encode the _whole_ data structure again, not just the piece you edited. Alternatively, provide a [mcve] that illustrates what you want and what doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich, if you look at the code this is what i did, the only part missing is $result = json_encode($datas);
 var_dump($result); removed because json isn't working. I provided the json in my first post, you can test it with the code provided too :-) I missing something for sure :-(

Comment: You can [edit] your question to clarify it. Still, I can not reproduce it with this code, there are too many parts missing. That's what the link I gave explains.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some research I found the solution:

```
$id = $row->id;
    $data_json = $row->data;
    $decoded_json = json_decode($data_json, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    //var_dump($decoded_json);
    $datas = $decoded_json['cells'];
    foreach($datas as &$data) {
        $data['data'] = str_replace($rep,$string,$data['data']);
    }

    $decoded_json['cells'] = $datas;
    $data = json_encode($decoded_json, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    $execut = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE xxx_wpdatatables_rows SET data = %s WHERE id = %d", $data, $id));
```

Just needed to add pointer (in php) for &$data to just modify and after encode all data...